# ¿problema con el *ngfor y el constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

buenos dias/tardes/noches/ madrugadas... tengo un pequeño problema con un tutorial que estaba siguiendo es este:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAMX042tfhU&t=824s

aproximadamente en el min 8:15 empieza la explicación de que es lo que va ha hacer con el `*ngfor` y aquí es donde surge mi problema ya que como estoy escribiendo aquí significa que, pues... no resulto del todo, en vs code; el problema inicia cuando el debuger me marca un error:

Property 'title' does not exist on type 'object'.

hasta ahí todo normal. pero no e podido encontrar una solución satisfactoria en la web que me resuleva el problema con el `constructor()` el código TS es el siguiente:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Registro';
  message = '';
  registered = false;
  nombre:string = "";
  apellido:string = "";
  entrys:object[];


  constructor(){

    this.entrys=[
      {title:"hola1"},
      {title:"hola2"},
      {title:"hola3"},
      {title:"hola4"},
      {title:"hola5"},
      {title:"hola6"},
    ]
  }


  Register()
  {

    this.registered = true;
    
    this.message = "user registered"

  }
}
```

y el código HTML para que mas o menos se den la idea es este:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form>

  <input type="text" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]= "nombre"><br/>

  <input type="text" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]= "apellido"><br/>

  <input type="submit" name="registrar" (click)="Register()"><br/>


</form>

<br/>

<p *ngIf="registered; else notregistered">{{message}} con el nombre de {{nombre}} {{apellido}}</p>

<ng-template #notregistered>

  <p>nadie registrado</p>

</ng-template>
<br/>
<br/>

<ul>
<li *ngFor='let entry of entrys'>{{entry.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

el error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para concluir y no alargar mas este meollo, ¿aqui que procede?, ¿Qué se esta haciendo mal?.

de antemano gracias por su tiempo en ayudarme.

Comment: `*ngFor` es para arreglos, y no para objetos, el error mismo te esta diciendo que estas intentando usar el `*ngFor` en un objeto y no en un arreglo primitivo.

Answer (score 2):

> Cuando lo defines como un array de objetos no le decís al compilador
> que pueden contener esos objetos Al definir una interfaz y asignarle a
> entrys el tipo Entrys [] el compilador sabe que puede esperar que
> contenga esa variable por lo cual no dará error al compilar En las
> nuevas versiones de Angular el modo es estricto  no admite tampoco
> al tipo  entrys:any[]; puede salvarse en el templete con $any pero lo
> mejor es definir los tipos correctamente da una forma de programar
> ordenada legible y evita errores de pasar variables undefine o null

[operators](https://angular-io.translate.goog/guide/template-expression-operators?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=nui,sc)

https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Me parece adecuado definir una interface

```js
interface Entrys{
    title:string
}


export class AppComponent {

  
  title = 'Registro';
  message = '';
  registered = false;
  nombre:string = "";
  apellido:string = "";

/*
Luego podemos crear una variable asignando la interface como si fuera un tipo
*/
  entrys:Entrys[];


  constructor(){

    this.entrys=[
      {title:"hola1"},
      {title:"hola2"},
      {title:"hola3"},
      {title:"hola4"},
      {title:"hola5"},
      {title:"hola6"},
    ]
  }


  Register()
  {

    this.registered = true;
    
    this.message = "user registered"

  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué? ¿Qué puedo aprender mirando tu respuesta? Nada, es puro código sin explicación.

Comment: agregue explicación en el código

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en usar `object` como el tipo de dato para `entrys`. Al hacer eso se buscará la propiedad `title` y esa propiedad no existe en `object`.

Puedes solucionarlo usando `any`:

```
entrys:any[];
```

Si en el video funciona con `object` puede ser por alguna configuración aplicada al compilador de typescript o por una diferencia entre versiones.